# EM algorithm maximize which objective function

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

In Wikipedia EM algorithm section of [Gaussian Mixture examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Gaussian_mixture) , there are two likelihood functions:

1. incomplete-data likelihood function $L(\theta;\mathbf{x})$
2. complete-data likelihood function $L(\theta; \mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$

which do we optimize when performing EM algorithm, why?

I was told by the tutor we optimize formula 2 as formula 1 won't give us the right clustering results. I don't fully agree with what he said. Sure we are optimize formula 2, I agree on that. But the reason is that we are not able to set derivative to zero directly for formula 1 according to [Andrew Ng's notes (last paragraph on page 1)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes7b.pdf). However, there's a way to get us out of the difficulty, using [Jensen's inequality (page 3)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf), that is, applying Jensen's inequality to formula 1. Calculations on formula 1 shows that formula 2 is indeed an intermediate step of formula 1. So formula 1 also can provide us the same results/right clustering as formula 2 as well. This is my understanding of the relations between formulas 1 and 2, please correct me if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 5):

Expectation-Maximization optimizes the incomplete-data **log-likelihood**, which is typically denoted by $L(\theta ; \mathbf{x})$. Which is slightly different w.r.t. what you stated in your first bullet.

Of course, since the logarithm is a monotonic increasing function, maximizing the log-likelihood is equivalent to maximizing the likelihood.

I just wanted to state this difference because the correct definition of $L(\theta ; \mathbf{x})$ and $L(\theta ; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})$ plays an important role next. Thus, just to be clear:

$$
L(\theta ; \mathbf{x}) := \log p(\mathbf{x} ; \theta) \\
L(\theta ; \mathbf{x,z}) := \log p(\mathbf{x,z} ; \theta)
$$

As you mentioned, one cannot directly solve (not even locally solve) $\arg\max_\theta L(\theta ; \mathbf{x})$ in many cases (e.g. Gaussian Mixture Models). Instead, one can (locally) maximize a lower bound on $L(\theta ; \mathbf{x})$ in order to solve the optimization problem.

In the Expectation-Maximization algorithm, this lower bound is the **expected value** of the complete-data **log-likelihood**, 
$L(\theta ; \mathbf{x, z})$, with respect to $p(\mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x} ; \theta^{(t)})$. Notice in bold the difference w.r.t. what you wrote in your second bullet.

This lower bound is typically denoted as $Q(\theta ; \theta^{(t)})$:
$$
Q(\theta; \theta^{(t)}) = 
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{z}| \mathbf{x}; \theta^{(t)}}[ L(\theta; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})] = 
\sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(\mathbf{z}| \mathbf{x}; \theta^{(t)}) L(\theta ; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) =
\sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(\mathbf{z}| \mathbf{x}; \theta^{(t)}) \log p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z} ; \theta )
$$

EM directly maximizes this lower bound, which indirectly also maximizes $L(\theta ;  \mathbf{x})$.

You can find a proof that $Q(\theta ; \theta^{(t)})$ is a lower bound of $L(\theta ; \mathbf{x})$ in the Wikipedia or in Andrew Ng's document on Jensen's inequality that you referenced.